# How to create source tarball release of package with npm without publishing it

Tags: node.js, npm, release

I want to make source tarball release of npm package without publishing it, something similar as in python:

`python setup.py sdist`

I want to also specify which files to include, something similar like `MANIFEST.in` file in python.

I know i can publish package to npm and that creates tarball, but this is my private project and i don't want to have it published.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> If no arguments are supplied, then npm packs the current package folder.

there is `npm pack` which packs the current directory, but there is no command to specify files to include, instead of doing that specify `.npmignore` to ignore files that you don't want inside the package.

also set `private:true` to `package.json` to prevent npm from publishing the package.

Comment: Only the files included in `"files" and "main"` will be included along with the `package.json`.  `"files"` can include `folder-paths as well`